# Making sense of a list of GPS values in an iOS application

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios, gps, cllocation

I have a web service that interfaces with the google maps API to generate a polygon on a google map. The service takes the GPS values and stores them for retrieval.

The problem is that when I try and use these values on my iPhone app the MKPolyline is just either a mess or a bunch of zig-zag lines.

Is there a way to make sense of these values so I can reconstruct the polygon?

My current code looks like this

```
private void GenerateMap()
    {
        var latCoord = new List<double>();
        var longCoord = new List<double>();
        var pad = AppDelegate.Self.db.GetPaddockFromCrop(crop);
        mapMapView.MapType = MKMapType.Standard;
        mapMapView.ZoomEnabled = true;
        mapMapView.ScrollEnabled = false;

        mapMapView.OverlayRenderer = (m, o) =>
        {
            if (o.GetType() == typeof(MKPolyline))
            {
                var p = new MKPolylineRenderer((MKPolyline)o);
                p.LineWidth = 2.0f;
                p.StrokeColor = UIColor.Green;
                return p;
            }
            else
                return null;
        };

        scMapType.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch (scMapType.SelectedSegment)
            {
                case 0:
                    mapMapView.MapType = MKMapType.Standard;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mapMapView.MapType = MKMapType.Satellite;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mapMapView.MapType = MKMapType.Hybrid;
                    break;
            }
        };

        if (pad.Boundaries != null)
        {
            var bounds = pad.Boundaries.OrderBy(t => t.latitude).ThenBy(t => t.longitude).ToList();
            foreach (var l in bounds)
            {
                double lat = l.latitude;
                double lon = l.longitude;

                latCoord.Add(lat);
                longCoord.Add(lon);
            }

            if (latCoord.Count != 0)
            {
                if (latCoord.Count > 0)
                {
                    var coord = new List<CLLocationCoordinate2D>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < latCoord.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        var c = new CLLocationCoordinate2D();
                        c.Latitude = latCoord[i];
                        c.Longitude = longCoord[i];
                        coord.Add(c);
                    }
                    var line = MKPolyline.FromCoordinates(coord.ToArray());  
                    mapMapView.AddOverlay(line);
                    mapMapView.SetVisibleMapRect(line.BoundingMapRect, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

MKPolygon / MKPolygonRenderer gives the same sort of random line mess. The OrderBy LINQ makes no difference other than to make the random lines a zig-zag going up or down the view.

Comment: Are you storing the timestamp at which each coordinate was taken, or just a pair of coordinate values?

Comment: The iOS renderer draws the lines in the exact order given. You have to remember the order of the coordinates and give them to the MKPolygon in the same order.  Otherwise, you have to try to re-construct the polygon with a "best guess" as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the order the points were captured in, you can't trace the actual path traveled around the perimeter of the paddock; this is why your polylines are turning into silly-walks all over the map.  Lacking that information, you can at best make an educated guess.

Some possible heuristics you might want to try:

- Take the average of all the points to get a "somewhere in the middle" point, then order by
   `atan2(l.latitude - middle.latitude, l.longitude - middle.longitude)`.  (Be careful, `atan2` is undefined at `(0, 0)`!)
- Take the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the points captured: for a relatively small number of points you can get away with the simple quadratic time [Jarvis's march](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm).  This has the approximate effect of wrapping a notional rubber band around the outside of the map push-pins by discarding points that would form concavities, and should also give you the order of the remaining points.